# How do I generate a custom response when a script times out due to blocking io?

Tags: php, iis, io, serial-port, blocking

## Goal

I am developing a JSON endpoint that basically reads data from a server-side COM port into a file (on the server end) when a user sends a GET request to it. The response from the server has to be a properly formed JSON response containing the name of the file where the contents were dumped to. If the COM port takes too long to respond, the file is closed and still considered valid with whatever contents it did read from the COM port. A valid response is still provided.

## Problem

When the COM port is no longer being fed data, it blocks until the script times out. This results in an error and IIS provides a generic error page on a json endpoint. This is not valid json, but it also does not contain the name of the file where the com data was dumped to.

## Details

- I have to use the PHP Direct IO extension to interface with a serial com port.
- This is blocking IO, and on windows, asynchronous IO is not supported (as far as I have seen.)
- register_shutdown_function does not guarantee it is executed while a connection is still open to the client, so I cannot use this to print a valid response.

Comment: What determines the name of the file? Does the PHP script create it, or does it already exist?

Comment: Filename is generated server-side. Php script creates the new file. Hmm, I could have the client choose it. There must be some way to work with blocking io though. Hmm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your JSON endpoint, you could create a wrapper script that calls your IO script. Set a timeout for your attempt to get a response from it, and then return JSON with either whatever it got from the script, or some custom message if the script timed out.

```
$timeout = 5;  // some reasonable time less than the wrapper script timeout

$data = ['filename' => 'something'];            // create the file name
$q = http_build_query($data);                   // pass it to the IO script

$context = stream_context_create(['http'=> ['timeout' => $timeout]]);
$response =  file_get_contents("http://yourserver/io_script.php?$q", false, $context);

echo json_encode($data + ['data' => $response ?: 'no data']);
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems a little finicky though but it seems like the best route available. I think the best option would be to have a local script that does the IO and execute with shell_exec (which is possible to set a timeout period on) and just set a timeout on that to less than a timeout set with set_time_limit. That way I am not fighting with the server configuration too much as long as set_time_limit is supported.

Comment: Yeah, I agree that sounds better. I answered with things I knew you would definitely be able to use based on what you were already doing, since not everyone has shell_exec enabled. But the general idea's about the same.